# Conceptually, what is phase?

Tags: phase

I get it mathematically and how it shows different waveforms in relation to each other on a graph but I am struggling to understand the real world significance and the implications. Like I hear people say phrases like voltage leads the current. Does this describe the the ohmic relationship between voltage and current? If so, what would it then mean for the case where voltage and current are in phase?

Comment: Phase is time delay.  If voltage and current are in phase, then there is no time delay between their peaks and valleys.

Comment: Phase is time difference as measured in units of the time it takes for something to cycle. All concepts lead to concepts. Not sure what kind of real world implications you are looking for.

Comment: This [function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbAeu.png) will press on defining the meaning of phase.

Comment: TLDR: As explained by answers below, there can never be any phase difference between voltage and current in a purely resistive circuit element. There can only be a phase shift in a circuit element that behaves like a capacitor or an inductor—circuit elements that _do not obey Ohm's law._

Answer (score 1):

"Ohmic" means a relationship that obeys Ohm's law \$V=I \times R\$. That is, current through some element is always proportional to the potential difference across that element, with the constant of proportionality being resistance \$R\$. This is the behaviour of a resistor. In such a relationship, this proportionality has two features:

1. The graph of current vs. voltage is a straight line. When current doubles, voltage doubles.
2. The line passes through the origin. When current is zero, voltage is also zero.

For the simple circuit below, the current source is swept from −10A to +10A, and the resulting voltage across resistor R1 is plotted:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQJNX3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Since the voltage \$V\$ across the resistor (as measured by voltmeter VM1) is always some fixed multiple \$R\$ of current \$I\$, you would expect that if the current were varying sinusoidally, the voltage across the resistor would also be a sinusoid, with peaks aligning perfectly in time with current peaks, and zero-crossings aligning with zero crossings of current:

[image]
[image]

There can be no phase difference, or "shift", between current and voltage in an ohmic element, because ohmic implies direct proportionality between the two.

Since the peaks, troughs and zero-crossings all coincide, these two waveforms are "in phase", as will be the case for current and voltage in any ohmic device, in any resistor.

---

By contrast, inductors and capacitors (which are not ohmic) have a very different relationship between their voltage current. A capacitor's current is related to the voltage across it by this equation:

$$ I = C\frac{dV}{dt} $$

It's saying that current \$I\$ through capacitance \$C\$ is *not* proportional to voltage, but rather to the *rate of change* of voltage \$V\$ over time. The term \$\frac{dV}{dt}\$ is the derivative of \$V\$, a measure of how fast \$V\$ is *changing*, in volts-per-second.

If you paid attention in math class, you'll know that the derivative of \$sin(t)\$ is \$cos(t)\$, and we should therefore expect to see that same relationship between current and voltage if we pass a sinusoidal current through a capacitor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkyCMi.png)</sup>

This is current, then voltage:

[image]
[image]

As expected, if the bottom waveform (voltage) is a sine \$V=sin(t)\$, then the top waveform (current) is a cosine \$I=\frac{d(sin(t))}{dt}=cos(t)\$.

It's clear that these waveforms differ in phase with respect to each other, by exactly one-quarter wavelength, or 90°. In the case of a capacitor, then, current peaks at a quarter-wavelength *prior* to voltage, and we say that current "leads" voltage by 90°, or that voltage "lags" current by 90°.

---

Sticking with the capacitor for a while, there is an interesting consequence to this behaviour. As you no doubt know, the *power* being received by some element is, at any instant in time, equal to the product of the voltage across it, and the current through it:

$$ P = I \times V $$

If we plot the *product* of current and voltage of the above two waveforms (which, remember, are 90° out of phase with respect to each other), which yields *power*, we get this:

[image]

This is showing that during certain intervals, power is *positive* (+80mW), indicating that that the capacitor is *receiving* energy, but importantly, it's also negative half the time (−80mW), which says that the capacitor is losing energy, and giving it back to the current source. This is because the capacitor is able to both store and relinquish energy, from and back to the rest of the circuit it's connected to.

That's something a resistor is is unable to do. A resistor can only ever *receive* energy, converting it to heat. Referring back to the plots of resistor current and voltage (where both waveforms are *in phase*), their product (power) looks like this:

[image]

Power in a resistor is *always* positive, telling you that it always receives energy, never giving it back. This makes sense when you think that ohmic direct proportionality means that current and voltage always have the same sign, and therefore their product is always positive.

That should help you understand why the phase difference of 90° between *capacitor* current and voltage is so important; it permits the product of current and voltage to be periodically *negative*, which can never happen for a resistor.

---

Interesting things can be done with waveforms of differing phase, say two voltages that vary sinusoidally, but have peaks that don't coincide. When you add two such waveforms together, their sum will be another sinusoid of *different amplitude*. Here are two voltages out of phase by 45° (blue and orange), and their sum (brown):

[image]

Notably, the brown sum waveform is out of phase with both original source waveforms. So, not only can you produce an arbitrary amplitude of sinusoid, you can also control its phase with respect to the two sources.

Now when the signals are 135° out of phase with each other:

[image]

Finally, and I hope this doesn't need explanation, we can make the signal disappear altogether by combining a sinusoid with itself phase-shifted by 180°:

[image]

If we use a capacitor to produce a phase shift, as we did above, and we employ an op-amp with feedback to add together some signal and a phase shifted version of itself, we create a filter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV7JWv.png)</sup>

It's too involved to explain completely here, but capacitor C1 will pass a current that leads the output voltage by 90°, and whose amplitude varies with frequency (due to the \$\frac{dV}{dt}\$ term). The op-amp combines the original signal with this phase-shifted, varying amplitude copy, producing an output with amplitude depending on frequency.

Pretty much every analogue circuit in existence depends on some such "superposition" of sinusoids being phase shifted with respect to each other, to produce a another signal with some desired phase and amplitude relationship with the original. This principle is at the heart of control systems theory, upon which the above circuit, and every other, depends.

Comment: Impressive simulations (especially for power)... It would be nice if the three graphs (of voltage, current and power) were right next to each other or the three quantities were superimposed for easy visual comparison. Once this topic is touched upon, it would be interesting to explain (in an intuitive manner) why in an op-amp integrating circuit the current leads the voltage by exactly 90° and in the equivalent passive RC circuit by less.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I couldn't get CircuitLab to coincide the zero lines for voltage and current, and the resulting graphs were offset from each other. I felt that was misleading, and was forced to separate the graphs.

Comment: Maybe the reason is in the CircuitLab autoscaling.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist That is certainly the reason.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this describe the the ohmic relationship between voltage and current?

No.  It describes the timing relationship between voltage and current.

Phase is easiest to understand in the context of periodic waveforms, such as sine waves or square waves.  If you look at the voltage across and current through a resistor when driven by a sine wave, you will see that the voltage waveform and current waveform overlay each other perfectly (adjusted for scale).  That is, the positive peaks, zero crossings, negative peaks, and all of the other points on the two waveforms perfectly overlay.

If you do the same thing with a capacitor, you will see that the voltage and current waveforms have the same shape, but are not synchronized in time.  The current leads the voltage.  Looking at the two waveforms on a scope, moving through the image from left to right, the first current zero crossing happens before the first voltage zero crossing.  That is, the current leads the voltage in phase.

For any periodic waveform, you can divide one cycle into 360 time segments.  Another way to describe the waveform is that it has 360 degrees.  Back to the capacitor waveforms, the current leads the voltage by 1/4 of one cycle, or 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of phase as an offset in the temporal dimension (usually, in reference to another signal or periodic quantity).

The idea is no different than, for example, an offset in voltage. If you you hook a battery up to an AC voltage such that the battery "rides" the AC source, you have an offset in voltage (Vac + Vbat). The only difference between this "DC offset" riding the wave is it describes the magnitude (in the vertical axis) while in the phase example, we're talking about an offset in the time dimension.

Answer (score 0):

The real world significance is mostly in power transmission. The other explanations of how phase is defined in capacitors and inductors are very good so I won't go into more detail here, but if a device that you are plugging into an outlet has a non-zero phase angle, then it has some *overall* energy storage portion to its power consumption. This storage can be inductive or capacitive, but it means that for e.g. a motor, extra energy has to go in to generate a magnetic field with one polarity then, later on in the waveform, that built up energy has to be removed and the magnetic field has to be built up in the opposite polarity, over and over. This energy isn't dissipated like in a resistor, it gets "returned" to the source but the transmission lines, transformers, and generators that supply it all have to be sized to handle this extra current going out and coming back in.

For our inductive load, we can minimize the amount of extra current by adding a capacitor in parallel with the coil. Since the phase angles of inductors and capacitors are 180 degrees out of phase, the capacitor will release energy into the inductor when its magnetic field is being built up and absorb energy when the magnetic field is collapsing, so none of it has to come from or return to the source.  When they are perfectly sized, the device will *overall* have its input current and voltage "matched" and the phase angle will be zero - the same as a resistor. This is one way to perform "power factor correction" (power factor is defined as the cosine of phase angle and the closer it is to 1, the less "extra" current needs to flow).